# how to use vision.ShapeInserter in matlab?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

when I compile the command line, it is error. I do not know what is wrong? any any help. Thanks!

Create the shape inserter object.

```
shapeInserter = vision.ShapeInserter;
#%Read the input image.

I = imread('cameraman.tif');
#%Define the rectangle dimensions as [x y width height].

rectangle = int32([10 10 30 30]);
#%Draw the rectangle and display the result.

J = step(shapeInserter, I, rectangle);
imshow(J);
```

Error:

> Undefined variable "vision" or function "vision.ShapeInserter".
>
> Error in ve_hcn (line 3)
>   shapeInserter = vision.ShapeInserter;
>
> ### ver :
>
> MATLAB Version: 8.0.0.783 (R2012b)
>   MATLAB License Number: 724504
>   Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Version 6.2 (Build 9200)
>   Java Version: Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server >VM mixed mode
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- MATLAB                                                Version 8.0
>   (R2012b) Communications System Toolbox                         Version
>   5.3        (R2012b) Control System Toolbox                                Version 9.4        (R2012b) DSP System Toolbox
>   Version 8.3        (R2012b) Image Processing Toolbox
>   Version 8.1        (R2012b) MATLAB Compiler
>   Version 4.18       (R2012b) MATLAB Report Generator
>   Version 3.13       (R2012b) Optimization Toolbox
>   Version 6.2.1      (R2012b) Parallel Computing Toolbox
>   Version 6.1        (R2012b) Partial Differential Equation Toolbox
>   Version 1.1        (R2012b) Signal Processing Toolbox
>   Version 6.18       (R2012b) Statistics Toolbox
>   Version 8.1        (R2012b) Symbolic Math Toolbox
>   Version 5.9        (R2012b)

Answer (score 2):

`vision.ShapeInserter` is in the Computer Vision System Toolbox, which you don't seem to have installed.  In the same toolbox (since release R2013a) there is also a function `insertShape`, which is easier to use.